# InvalidElementStateException:

Tags: python, selenium

This question has been asked in a similar fashion, but not with the same parameters and some answers are mixed. I currently have geckowebdriver, selenium 3.5.9. with python 2.7.10. I ran the following test in pycharm:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

import unittest

class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("https://www.rosoka.com/")

    def test_Login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        rosokaUsername = "dsmith"
        rosokaPassword = "Whorunit1!"
        loginFieldID = "edit-name"
        passFieldID = "edit-pass"
        loginButtonXpath = "//input[@value ='Log in']"


        loginFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(loginFieldID))
        passFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(passFieldID))
        loginButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(loginButtonXpath))

        loginFieldElement.clear()
        loginFieldElement.send_keys(rosokaUsername)
        passFieldElement.clear()
        passFieldElement.send_keys(rosokaPassword)
        loginButtonElement.click()


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

I am getting:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
InvalidElementStateException: Message: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

When I navigate to that site, the login form fields are not visible,  I have to click on the "User Portal" link to see them.  So your script should do the same thing.

1. wait for the user portal link to be clickable
2. click on it
3. proceed with the rest of your clicks  (note, you may need to wait for the form to be visible after you click on the user portal link)

Comment: Moreover `loginFieldID` in `driver.find_element_by_id(loginFieldID)` etc seems to me as a placeholder rather than being the actual ones.